# SQL query to count entries in multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database with two tables, tblPlayers and tblMatches.

tblPlayers contains the following fields: playerID, playerName.

tblMatches contains matchID, scorer1ID, scorer2ID, scorer3ID.

I need to run a query to count the total number of goals scored by a player, and return it with their playerID.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT
tblPlayers.playerID, tblPlayers.playerName, count(*) AS goals
FROM
tblPlayers, matches
WHERE
(tblPlayers.playerID = tblMatches.scorer1ID
OR
tblPlayers.playerID = tblMatches.scorer2ID
OR
tblPlayers.playerID = tblMatches.goalscorer3ID)
GROUP BY tblPlayers.playerID
ORDER BY goals DESC
```

However, this isn't working as required, as the count function doesn't allow for the fact that a player can score more than one goal in a game (e.g. if a player scores three goals his ID appears in the scorer1ID field, scorer2ID field and scorer3ID field, but the count just returns a value of 1, when it needs to be 3).

Hope that makes sense, I've been tearing my hair out for the last few days trying to solve this! Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if there are more than 3 goals in a match?

Comment: Did you set up the tables this way? I think there are more efficient ways to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    playerID,
    playerName,
    SUM(goals) AS goals
FROM 
(
    SELECT p.playerID, p.playerName, COUNT(*) AS goals
    FROM 
        tblPlayers p
        JOIN tblMatches m ON m.scorer1ID = p.playerID
    GROUP BY p.playerID, p.playerName

    UNION ALL

    SELECT p.playerID, p.playerName, COUNT(*) AS goals
    FROM 
        tblPlayers p
        JOIN tblMatches m ON m.scorer2ID = p.playerID
    GROUP BY p.playerID, p.playerName

    UNION ALL

    SELECT p.playerID, p.playerName, COUNT(*) AS goals
    FROM 
        tblPlayers p
        JOIN tblMatches m ON m.scorer3ID = p.playerID
    GROUP BY p.playerID, p.playerName
) sub
GROUP BY playerID, playerName
```

Or, here's a query that does it in one pass:

```
SELECT 
    p.playerID, 
    p.playerName, 
    SUM (
        CASE WHEN p.playerID = m.scorer1ID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN p.playerID = m.scorer2ID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN p.playerID = m.scorer3ID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ) AS goals
FROM 
    tblPlayers p
    JOIN tblMatches m ON p.playerID IN (m.scorer1ID, m.scorer2ID, m.scorer3ID)
GROUP BY p.playerID, p.playerName
```

Comment: +1 and thanks for the upvote on my now deleted answer. I'm sure you were working it out before you saw mine. Nice use of `IN` on the JOIN btw.

Comment: That's brilliant, many thanks for your help. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

That is a terrible table design, but if you are stuck with it then the following should do:

```
SELECT
tblPlayers.playerID, tblPlayers.playerName,  
(select count(*) from tblMatches m where p.playerId = m.Scoreer1Id)
+
(select count(*) from tblMatches m where p.playerId = m.Scoreer2Id)
+
(select count(*) from tblMatches m where p.playerId = m.Scoreer3Id)
from tblPlayers p
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It uses embedded select statements to sum the number of times a player shows up in each columnn

```
SELECT tblPlayers.playerID, tblPlayers.playerName, ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblPlayers, matches WHERE tblPlayers.playerID = tblMatches.scorer1ID) + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblPlayers, matches WHERE tblPlayers.playerID = tblMatches.scorer2ID) + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblPlayers, matches WHERE tblPlayers.playerID = tblMatches.scorer2ID)) As [GoalsScored] 
FROM tblPlayers
WHERE
(tblPlayers.playerID = tblMatches.scorer1ID
OR
tblPlayers.playerID = tblMatches.scorer2ID
OR
tblPlayers.playerID = tblMatches.goalscorer3ID)
GROUP BY tblPlayers.playerID
ORDER BY goals DESC
```